# Ambiguity in "hear from". Can it be used either way?

Tags: grammar

"Can God hear me from heaven?".
[can God hear me from where he is?]

"Can God hear me from earth?"

[I cry out to God from earth but can he hear me?]

Comment: Yes, it can be used either way.

Comment: okay but I posted a similar example elsewhere and they said it was ambiguous. This was the example. "I heard some noises from the basement." [some noises from the basement were heard by me]  they said I could add "coming" to avoid ambiguity.  "I heard some noises coming from the basement".

Comment: Yes, it can be ambiguous. In the me/God case, it's normally understood that God is in heaven and I am on Earth, so there's little ambiguity. In the basement case, it's not impossible for me to be in the basement so it's ambiguous whether I am in the basement and the sounds are coming from somewhere else or I am somewhere else and the sounds are coming from the basement. If there is no other context, most people would guess that I am elsewhere and the sounds come from the basement, but it is possible it's the other way around, so it is technically ambiguous.